# Opencv C++/Python bind of std::vector<myType>

Tags: python, c++, opencv, binding, stdvector

I'm adding a OpenCV module following [this](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html).

I've created classes and functions and this works ok :)

However, when I want to create a function that takes as parameter a `std::vector<myType>` where `myType` was declared using opencv's directive for binding:

```
struct CV_EXPORTS_W_SIMPLE myType { //Also tried with CV_EXPORTS_W
    // Stuff
};
```

My function looks like this (it's a class method):

```
CV_WRAP void myFunction(std::vector<mytype>){
//stuff
}
```

When I compile I get a long errors that starts by:

```
/source/build/pyopencv_generated_types.h:278:5: error: ‘vector_mytype’ was not declared in this scope
     vector_mytype vmytype0;
```

Which makes me think I have to manually declare my class' vector bind somewhere (cv2.cpp?) how do I achieve this?

Comment: [here is an example](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/4.x/modules/barcode/misc/python/pyopencv_barcode.hpp)

Comment: @berak thanks! You may want to describe it in an answer :)